# Question on beforeUpdate or afterUpdate trigger in Salesforce

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, future, after-trigger

I have some doubts on whether I should be using a beforeUpdate or an afterTrigger for the scenario enlisted below. Any pointers would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

I have a custom object ABC which has a status field and when the status of that field changes to Approved, I need to perform the below operations.

1. I need to first set the status of the field which was previously Approved to Executing.
2. I then need to update about 10 custom object records.
3. Finally after Step3 is completed, I will need to change the status again from Executing to Finished.

My confusion is whether I need to use beforeUpdate or afterUpdate trigger. Since I need to update the status from Approved to Executing to Finished, I believe I need to use beforeUpdate. However, I also need to do a lot of processing on related records and so I feel afterUpdate is the way to go.

The way I am planning to do this is to call an @future method in either the beforeUpdate or afterUpdate in the trigger and to then perform all the processing asynchronously in the @future method.

Please give me some advice on the decision of beforeUpdate vs afterUpdate and also about calling the @future method in the trigger. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you did this all synchronously the double status change would be irrelevant and unnecessary (only the second change to Finished would ever be visible in the DB). If the related object processing is significant, doing it synchronously will probably hit governor limits. Using future from trigger is a broken pattern, despite Salesforce's recommendations. I have a solution [here](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/) that sounds like a good fit for your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When an approver approves a records, the status changes to approved and that is when I need to kick off the processing. However, I need to do significant processing and thus decided to run it asynchronously. Also, the order of execution in processing related records is very important for me - first accounts, then contacts, contracts etc and thus decided to hand it to off to a future and then execute the logic one method after another. Do you think future from a trigger is a very bad idea or something that should be avoided, but can be used?

Comment: Read [the article I wrote](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/). I explain why using a future is a bad idea, and even using the replacement (Queueable) won't work in all scenarios. Decoupling via a Platform Event is far more robust and much less likely to hit governor limit issues (including daily limits on async).